# Slurm only using all CPUs on some software when using srun?

Tags: multithreading, cluster-computing, slurm, stdasync, sbatch

I have a script defined like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=16
#SBATCH --mem 180000

./program1 --threads 16
./program2 --threads 16
```

I then submit my job with `sbatch job.sh`

The thing is that program1 uses all 16 cores/cpus, but program2 does only use 1 (both are supposedly multi-thread). If I however modify the script to be like:

```
#!/bin/sh

#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=16
#SBATCH --mem 180000

./program1 --threads 16
srun --mpi=openmpi ./program2 --threads 16
```

then program2 does also use all 16 cores. Why is it necessary to add that "srun"?

As extra information, the implementation of program2 multithreading is done using `std::async`

Comment: What happens, in your first script, if program2 appears before program1?

Comment: Exactly the same! @JeffHolt

Comment: @Ivan By exactly the same, you meant program1 still uses 16 cores? when program2 is above program1?

I can explain in detail if you clarify this point.^

Comment: @bozzmob no matter what I do or the order in which programs are run, with the first script program1 will use 16 cores and program2 will use 1. If I add the srun piece, then no matter the order, both use 16 cores